# Why does randomForest has higher test AUC than train AUC? Is this possible?

Tags: r, random-forest, auc

I am having some question with the randomForest. I use the "creatFolds" in "caret" package to partition the data into training set and test set. After building the model, I found that the test data has higher AUC than the training data. Is this possible? The following is code. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

```
library(randomForest)
library(pROC)
library(ROCR)
library(caret)
# prep training to binary outcome
train0 <- iris[iris$Species %in% c('virginica', 'versicolor'),]
train0$Species <- droplevels(train0$Species)
set.seed(1)
index <- createFolds(iris$Species, k = 2, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
train <- train0[index$Fold1,];train <- na.omit(train)
test <- train0[-index$Fold1,];test <- na.omit(test)
# build model
rfmodel <- randomForest(Species~., data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=2)

#the train AUC
rf_p_train <- predict(rfmodel, type="prob")[,2]
rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$Species)
r_auc_train <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]] 
r_auc_train   #0.8098

#the test AUC
rf_p_test <- predict(rfmodel, type="prob",newdata = test)[,2]
rf_pr_test <- prediction(rf_p_test, test$Species)
r_auc_test <- performance(rf_pr_test, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]] 
r_auc_test    #0.956
```

Comment: Split-sample validation requires around 20,000 observations to work well enough.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have 'testing' accuracy greater than your 'training' accuracy it generally means your model is **'underfit'** in contrast to **'overfit'**.  Basically, your model likely has more information it could learn from the data without 'memorizing' the data.  Looking at your code, this is very likely the case as you only used 2 trees in your `randomForest` call.  Usually this is closer to 500 with most models I have seen but YMMV.

Comment: Its really important to note that the variance of a random forest *lowers* with increase number of trees.  So really, the only bound on the number of trees you should use is your patience.  If you can afford to use thousands of trees, there's no reason not to.

Comment: Underfit would never result in higher performance though. Underfit results in a worse generalization of the model.

Comment: @Firebug I can generally agree with your statement, however, it is possible that an underfit model has sufficient information from the training dataset to do well on the specific test dataset provided.  It is likely however, that generalized across many test sets I too would expect it to do worse.